# MongoDB - Query nested array

Tags: mongodb

I'm having trouble querying document of the following format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6061f989337137b6196dfbf7"),
    "hostname" : "something-rather-random",
    "port_info" : {
            "Interfaces" : {
                    "Interface" : [
                            {
                                    "IfIndex" : "1628",
                                    "Name" : "Tunnel1",
                                    "AbbreviatedName" : "Tun1",
                                    "InOctets" : "0",
                                    "InUcastPkts" : "0",
                                    "InNUcastPkts" : "0",
                                    "InDiscards" : "0",
                                    "InErrors" : "0",
                                    "InUnknownProtos" : "0",
                                    "InRate" : "0",
                                    "OutOctets" : "0",
                                    "OutUcastPkts" : "0",
                                    "OutNUcastPkts" : "0",
                                    "OutDiscards" : "0",
                                    "OutErrors" : "0",
                                    "OutRate" : "0",
                                    "LastClear" : "2021-04-30T14:04:12"
                            },
                            {...}
                           ]
                        }
    },
    "poll_time" : "2021-05-04 14:00:09.065046"
```

}

Data that i'm trying to get out of this is `InErrors` for a specific `IfIndex` (known). Here is how I'm querying:

```
db.my_db.find({'hostname':'something-rather-random'}, {'port_info.Interfaces.Interface.IfIndex': '1628'}).pretty()
```

What I'm getting back is a list of dictionaries containing `IfIndex'es`.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in below MongoDB 4.4 in find method,

Try aggregation operator in find method starting from MongoDB 4.4,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `Interface` array and check condition for `IfIndex` field
- `$first` to get first matching element from above filtered result
- `$let` to declare a variable and initialise above result object in to `interface` variable, return only `InErrors` in result

```
db.my_db.find(
{ "hostname": "something-rather-random" },
{
  "InErrors": {
    $let: {
      vars: {
        interface: {
          $first: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$port_info.Interfaces.Interface",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.IfIndex", "1628"] }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      in: "$$interface.InErrors"
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zEfG7VFhbF_)